# Angular Compiler (ivy?) keeps complaining about used identifier/variable

Tags: angular

Every time I try to compile the project, this error pops up.

```
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/scrolling.js 23:12
Module parse failed: Identifier 'ɵngcc0' has already been declared (23:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import * as ɵngcc3 from '@angular/cdk/collections';
| 
> import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
| import * as ɵngcc1 from '@angular/cdk/platform';
| import * as ɵngcc2 from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
```

I have no idea where to begin debugging this. I have tried googling the error code but to no avail. Nobody else seemed to have this error before. Restarting `ng serve` does not solve the problem. I am using Angular 11 and Angular Material for the project.

How do I fix this and stop this error code from popping up?

Comment: Did you create a clean Angular project with `ng new`? What custom code have you added?  Can you share a sample project that will demonstrate the error?  Are you using a generic `ng serve` from the project root, or are you adding arguments to it?

Comment: You can try removing node_modules and running `npm install`.

Comment: @JeffryHouser yes, this is a brand new project. I created with `npm install -g @angular/cli`, `ng new angular-app`, `ng add @angular/material`. I am also using `ng serve`.

Comment: Thank you, @mbojko, deleting `/node_modules` and install npm packages solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I found also that:

```
closing VS Code, 
then deleting the node_modules, 
then opening VS Code
then running **npm install** worked.
```

Ian